# calendar_helper cannot be used with raw()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using calendar_helper with success using this code:

```
<%=  

calendar({:year => Date.today.year, :month => Date.today.month}) do |d|
  cell_text = "#{d.mday}" 
  cell_attrs = {:class => 'day'}
  @events.each do |e|
    if e.start_at.mday == d.mday
      cell_text << link_to( e.name, :action => 'show', :id => e ) << "<br />" 
      cell_attrs[:class] = 'specialDay'
    end
  end
  [cell_text, cell_attrs]
end

%>
```

This gives me the correct html, with events falling on this month's days being outputed correctly. However, this gives me the escaped code, so i need to pass it trough raw.

As soon as i pass it trough raw though, i lose the details on the calendar (events) and get only the calendar itself.

Any idea why this is happening or how to circumvent it?

Comment: I have something very similar that is working without the call to raw in a 3.1.1 app. It is generating the correct html without being escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the work I needed to do in a helper method and passed day and my collection (like your @events) to the helper method. It worked fine without a call to raw and left the view code much cleaner.

Comment: Dennis, can you please elaborate? Not sure what you did to resolve this issue?